# $(1 + a + b + c)(1+\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c)=16$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose $a, b, c\in\mathbb R^+$ are such that
$$(1 + a + b + c)\left(1+\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\right)= 16$$
Then prove $a + b + c = 3$.

I tried to solve this by trial and error, put $a=b=c=1$. But I want to know how to solve it mathematically.

Comment: Use Am GM inequality

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee How to use Am gm inequality

Comment: Chebyshev's Inequality...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(1 + a + b + c)(1+\frac {1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})= 4+(a+\frac {1}{a})+ (b+ \frac {1}{b})
  +(c+  \frac {1}{c})    +(a/b +b/a)+(a/c +c/a)+(b/c + c/b)\ge 16$$

Each expression in the parenthesis on RHS is $\ge 2$ and equality happens iff each quotient is $1$

Thus we have $a=b=c=1$ which implies $a+b+c =3$

Answer (score 4):

Use that
$$1+a+b+c\ge 4\sqrt[4]{abc}$$
$$1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\geq 4\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{abc}}$$
and multiply both.

Comment: How can this help me in proving $a+b+c=3$ without knowing explicitly what a,b,c,d are

Comment: it is known that it must be $a=b=c$ from the $ AM-GM$ this is the only case for the equal sign.OK?

Comment: Oh thanks ! It helps a lot

Comment: Should a send you a link for this Theorem?

Comment: Yes please .....

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Answer (score 1):

$(1 + a + b + c)\left(1+\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b+\dfrac1c\right)$

$=1+\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b+\dfrac1c+a+\dfrac{a}{a}+\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{a}{c}+b+\dfrac{b}{a}+\dfrac{b}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+c+\dfrac{c}{a}+\dfrac{c}{b}+\dfrac{c}{c}$

$=4+a+\dfrac{1}{a}+b+\dfrac{1}{b}+c+\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{a}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{b}+\dfrac{c}{a}+\dfrac{a}{c}$

$=4+\left(a+\dfrac{1}{a}\right)+\left(b+\dfrac{1}{b}\right)+\left(c+\dfrac{1}{c}\right)+\left(\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{a}\right)+\left(\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{b}\right)+\left(\dfrac{c}{a}+\dfrac{a}{c}\right)$

Each of the terms in brackets is $\ge 2$, so the equality holds if and only if $a=b=c=1$.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that $a=b=c=1$ is a solution.

We can also see, at least intuivitely, that there cannot be *other* solutions with $a+b+c=3$: If we make, say, $a$ *smaller* than $1$, then $\frac1a$ will *increase*, and the two other fractions cannot *decrease* by as much as that if we add the surplus from $a$ to either $b$ or $c$. And then we have $4$ times something larger than $4$, which does not make $16$.

So if what the exercise asks us to prove is true at all, it must be that $a=b=c=1$ is a *global minimum* of $(1+a+b+c)(1+\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c)$ on $\mathbb R_+{}^3$ -- because if this continuous function had values both above and below $16$ then the locus of the $16$s would be a surface rather than a single point.

This suggests that we might be able to structure a proof in two parts:

1. For every fixed $d>0$, the function $(1+a+b+c)(1+\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c)$ restricted to the plane $a+b+c=d$ has a global minimum at $a=b=c=d/3$.
2. The function $(1+3d)(1+\frac3d)$ has a global minimum at $d=1$.

The second of these is easy with calculus. The first would be a matter of making the intuition from above precise.

Comment: The proof by Mohammad Riazi-Kermani is a lot more elegant than this answer, but I'm letting it stand as an example of exploration the OP _could_ have tried.

Comment: The intuition in your answer is really help ful! Thanks